# Problem using jqGrid Search Function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid, but really want to get to grips with it. I am having a hard time getting the Search function to work. Here is the XML I am working with:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>1</total>
    <records>3</records>
        <row id='1'>
            <cell>1</cell>
            <cell>5 Little Roodee</cell>
            <cell>Hawarden</cell><cell>CH5 3PU</cell>
            <cell>895.00</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
        </row>
        <row id='2'>
            <cell>2</cell>
            <cell>28 Pant-y-Fawnog</cell>
            <cell>Buckley</cell>
            <cell>CH7 2PD</cell>
            <cell>610.00</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row id='3'>
            <cell>3</cell>
            <cell>60 Langford Crescent</cell>
            <cell>Buckley</cell>
            <cell>CH7 2PR</cell>
            <cell>625.00</cell>
            <cell>1</cell>
        </row>
</rows>
```

As you can see its fairly simple. Now here is the jqgrid declaration I am using:

```
$(function(){ 
          $("#list").jqGrid({
            url:'xml_properties_jq.php',
            datatype: 'xml',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:['ID','Address', 'Town','Postcode','Rent. Val','Active'],
            colModel :[ 
              {name:'property_id', index:'property_id', width:40}, 
              {name:'property_add_1', index:'property_add_1', width:150}, 
              {name:'property_add_town', index:'property_add_town', width:80, align:'right', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne']}}, 
              {name:'property_add_postcode', index:'property_add_postcode', width:80, align:'right'}, 
              {name:'property_rentable_value', index:'property_rentable_value', width:80, align:'right'}, 
              {name:'property_active', index:'property_active', width:60}
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            sortname: 'property_id',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Properties'
          })
          //jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
          .navGrid('#pager',{view:true, del:false}, 
{}, // use default settings for edit
{}, // use default settings for add
{},  // delete instead that del:false we need this
{multipleSearch : false}, // enable the advanced searching
{closeOnEscape:true} /* allow the view dialog to be closed when user press ESC key*/
);
});
```

Finally here is the PHP which constructs my XML:

```
<?php 
//include the information needed for the connection to MySQL data base server. 
// we store here username, database and password 
include("Connections/db.php");

// to the url parameter are added 4 parameters as described in colModel
// we should get these parameters to construct the needed query
// Since we specify in the options of the grid that we will use a GET method 
// we should use the appropriate command to obtain the parameters. 
// In our case this is $_GET. If we specify that we want to use post 
// we should use $_POST. Maybe the better way is to use $_REQUEST, which
// contain both the GET and POST variables. For more information refer to php documentation.
// Get the requested page. By default grid sets this to 1. 
$page = $_GET['page']; 

// get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid 
$limit = $_GET['rows']; 

// get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
// after that the index from colModel 
$sidx = $_GET['sidx']; 

// sorting order - at first time sortorder 
$sord = $_GET['sord']; 

// if we not pass at first time index use the first column for the index or what you want
if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; 

// connect to the MySQL database server 
//$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error()); 

// select the database 
//mysql_select_db($db) or die("Error connecting to db."); 
mysql_select_db($database_eazylet, $eazylet);

// calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this for paging the result 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM p_properties", $eazylet); 
//$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row['count']; 

// calculate the total pages for the query 
if( $count > 0 && $limit > 0) { 
              $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit); 
} else { 
              $total_pages = 0; 
} 

// if for some reasons the requested page is greater than the total 
// set the requested page to total page 
if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;

// calculate the starting position of the rows 
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;

// if for some reasons start position is negative set it to 0 
// typical case is that the user type 0 for the requested page 
if($start <0) $start = 0; 

// the actual query for the grid data 
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM p_properties ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit"; 
$result = mysql_query($SQL, $eazylet) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysql_error()); 

// we should set the appropriate header information. Do not forget this.
header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");

$s = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$s .=  "<rows>";
$s .= "<page>".$page."</page>";
$s .= "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
$s .= "<records>".$count."</records>";

// be sure to put text data in CDATA
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
//while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $s .= "<row id='". $row['property_id']."'>";            
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['property_id']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['property_add_1']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['property_add_town']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['property_add_postcode']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['property_rentable_value']."</cell>";
    $s .= "<cell>". $row['property_active']."</cell>";
    $s .= "</row>";
}
$s .= "</rows>"; 

echo $s;
?>
```

All the sorting works fine in the grid so I assume the data is OK.

My problem is that when I hit the search button, enter any valid criteria (i.e. ID = 1) and click FIND, nothing happens. The search box remains and the list has not been filtered.

I have been working on this all day without success so any help would be VERY gratefully received!!

I am using jquery v1.4.4 and jqgrid v3.8.2

Many thanks all

Si

Comment: The jqgrid will give php server three parameters searchField, searchString and searchOper Whar the single search SQL looks like? How to use that three parameters? Can you give me a example code? What's more, what the php server will give back to jqgrid after that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on which kind of [searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#searching) you use the server receive different additional parameters.

In case of [single field searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching) it will be `searchField`, `searchString` and `searchOper` parameter. In case of [advance searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching) one has one parameter `filters` which has in [the JSON encoded form](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options) the information about all parameters of the search request. In case of the [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) and additional parameter `stringResult:true` the format of parameters are the same as in case of [advance searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching).

So you should just append your code with the analyse of the parameters of searching request. You can download [the demo files](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/downloads/jqgrid_demo38.zip) from [the jqGrid download page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) and examine the code of search_adv.php file for example.

Comment: Im feeling a bit thick now. I have looked at all the examples I can find using XML data and a PHP script and I can't see anywhere they are processing anything other than the default URL parameters (page, rows, sidx, sord). Can you point me to a specific example I can use for reference?

Comment: @Simon S: In the search_adv.php file from the http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/downloads/jqgrid_demo38.zip you will see lines with `$_REQUEST['_search']` and `$_REQUEST['filters']` used as parameters for advanced searching. Then the function `constructWhere` will be called.

Comment: many thanks for that. The downloaded examples you pointed me to seem quite different from the ones in the demo pages on the Triand website. The other thing that helped me massively is the excellent jqGrid CRUD template found at http://suddendevelopment.com/?p=38